# SQL Split value between Month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a problem. I would like to split a value which represents the value paid for a booking in an hotel between months. So if the booking is between two months I need to add a row and split the relative value in each month.
My knoledge in SQL is not enough to be able to do it. Any tips would be appreciated.

```
name ;                  booking code;   Nation;     Adults; Children;  Month;       Start Date; End date;   N° nights;  Importo Netto (€);
Alexandra Ferreira;     HM2TNWSDN2;     Svizzera;   2;      0;         ;            31/07/2021  14/08/2021  14;         1671,26428571429;
Philippe Fisher;        HM2TRBHDYE;     Svizzera;   2;      0;         June;        13/06/2021  17/06/2021  4;          406,19;
Jean Claude Psauté;     HM3B9Z2H8F;     Francia;    1;      0;         June;        21/06/2021  25/06/2021  4;          406,16;
Magdalena Birrer;       HM49PWSDWN;     Svizzera;   2;      0;         March;       28/03/2021  01/04/2021  4;          313,617142857143;
Miriam Pahlke;          HM4MSX22CF;     Germania;   2;      0;         August;      20/08/2021  27/08/2021  7;          843,71;
Francesco  Mur;         HM4QQTWAFP;     Italia;     2;      0;         June;        26/06/2021  28/06/2021  2;          244,46;
Ulrika;                 Ulrika1;        Svezia;     3;      0;         ;            28/06/2021  18/07/2021  20;         2400;
```

And this is the result I would like

```
Name                booking code    Nation  Adults  Children    month   Start Date  End date    N° nights   Importo Netto (€)   booking date
Alexandra Ferreira  HM2TNWSDN2  Svizzera    2      0            July    31/07/2021  01/08/2021  1           119             13/02/2021
Alexandra Ferreira  HM2TNWSDN2  Svizzera    2      0            August  01/08/2021  14/08/2021  13          1.552           13/02/2021
Philippe Fisher     HM2TRBHDYE  Svizzera    2      0            June    13/06/2021  17/06/2021  4           406             16/05/2020
Jean Claude Psauté  HM3B9Z2H8F  Francia     1      0            June    21/06/2021  25/06/2021  4           406             06/03/2021
Magdalena Birrer    HM49PWSDWN  Svizzera    2      0            March   28/03/2021  01/04/2021  4           314             13/02/2021
Miriam Pahlke       HM4MSX22CF  Germania    2      0            August  20/08/2021  27/08/2021  7           844             18/03/2021
Francesco  Murianni HM4QQTWAFP  Italia      2      0            June    26/06/2021  28/06/2021  2           244             02/06/2020
Ulrika              Ulrika1     Svezia      3      0            June    28/06/2021  01/07/2021  3           360             02/06/2020
Ulrika              Ulrika1     Svezia      3      0            July    01/07/2021  18/07/2021  17          2.040           02/06/2020
```

Is this possibile with SQL?
thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products have their own, non-ANSI SQL compliant, functions.)

Comment: Start Date and End date data type?

Comment: Hi Jarlh!! I am using Microsoft Active X  DataObjects 6.1 which I control through VBA. The Start Date and End Date are DateTime

Comment: Does that imply MS SQL Server as dbms?

Comment: Yes it does!!!!